# Weird behavior with datetime

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

mysql
Rails 3.2.18

in console:

```
irb(main):056:0> Order.find(964179).delivery_target
=> Tue, 14 Jul 2015 13:13:21 CDT -05:00

irb(main):057:0> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select("select o.delivery_target from orders o where o.id=964179")
   (1.6ms)  select o.delivery_target from orders o where o.id=964179
=> [{"delivery_target"=>nil}]
```

Why is the delivery_target nil in the second example?

Comment: Do you have `delivery_target` method overridden in your model? What do you get with `Order.find(964179)[:delivery_target`?

Comment: Cool, thanks. You are right. Add the answer please I will vote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely it is caused by your own implementation of `delivery_target`, which is a common way for enhancing models. You can always check the real value in the database using `model[:delivery_target]`.